# Completion commutes with finite direct sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have been reading a couple of different places, that completion of module (or the $I$-adic completion to be more exact) commutes with finite direct sums. I was told, that it follows from the fact, that completion is an additive functor, but as I haven't worked with functors before, that doesn't make much sense to me, and I was wondering if it could be proven in another way (maybe from using the definition of completion only). I've been trying to work it around my self, but doesn't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by 'completion' here? Completion of a module, or what?

Comment: Yes completion of a module (or the $I$-adic completion to be more exact)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules.

The question is to show that there is an isomorphism $$\underbrace{\left(\varprojlim M / (I^n M)\right)\oplus\left(\varprojlim N / (I^n N)\right)}_{\text{Call this $A$}}\simeq \varprojlim (M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N))$$

One pedestrian way of showing this is by the universal property of inverse limits.

**First step:** we need to define projections $\pi_n:A\to (M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N))$.

An element of $A$ is a collection of elements $x_n\in M/(I^nM)$ compatible$^{*}$ with the inverse system, together with a likewise compatible collection of elements $y_n\in N/(I^nN)$ ($^{*}$the $x_n$ are projections of each other by the relevant maps). For such an $x\oplus y\in A$ define $$\pi_n(x\oplus y)={x_n\oplus y_n}\in (M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N)).$$

This makes sense since $$\left(M / (I^n M)\right)\oplus\left( N / (I^n N)\right)\simeq (M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N)).$$
It is straightforward to check that the $\pi_n$ are compatible with the inverse system $(M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N))$ (all relevant diagrams commute).

**Second step:** for every $R$-module $P$ and every set of maps $f_n:P\to (M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N))$ compatible with the inverse system, there is a unique map $F: P\to A$ such that all diagrams made of $F$, $f_n$, $\pi_n$ commute.

For an element $p\in P$, consider the collection of all first coordinates of all $f_n(p)$, together with the collection of all second coordinates of the $f_n(p)$: these collections together form an element of $A$, that we call $F(p)$. It is again straightforward to check that the relevant diagrams commute.

Finally, to see that $F$ is unique assume that there is another map $F'$ satisfying the same conditions. Then for all $n$, $\pi_n \circ F=\pi_n \circ F'$. This implies that $F=F'$ because if $x\oplus y\in A$ and $x'\oplus y'\in A$ are such that for all $n$, $x_n\oplus y_n=x'_n\oplus y'_n$, then $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.

Comment: This is of course straightforward but you should also prove that the map $F: P\to A$ making the diagrams commute is unique

Comment: @Max True, I will edit.

Comment: All the maps $F, f_n, \pi_n$ they are clearly $R$-linear, right? Or are there anything tricky to be aware of?

Comment: Nothing tricky at all. The only difficulty here is to write everything down. Everything follows mostly by definition, which is one reason why one could suspect that there is a language to make this proof much shorter, which is what category theory achieves.

Comment: Oh I see, thank! Just to be sure, what we are showing, is that $A$ actually is the inverse limit of the system defined by the collection $\{(M \oplus N)/ (I^n (M \oplus N))\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and hence we have the isomorphism we want?

Comment: @Jta This is what we do indeed.

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier: There is a small typo in your answer. $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules, not $A$-modules. Perhaps you could correct this typo. Thanks.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius You're right, especially since $A$ also does denote something in the answer. Thanks!