# Completion with respect to the topology defined by the subgroups of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, limits-colimits, formal-completions

Let $M$ be an toplogical abelian group.
I heard we can define $\hat{M}$ by completion of $M$ with respect to the topology defined by the subgroups of finite index.

For example, if $M=\Bbb{Z}$, then subgroups of finite index is exactly $n\Bbb{Z}$ and $\hat{M}=\varprojlim \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}=\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$.
In this example, inverse system is given by $\{\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}  (m\mid n)\}$

But it is difficult for me to understand we can define $\hat{M}$ for every topological abelian group $M$.
What is inverse system of the inverse limit for general $M$?

For example, if $M=E(K)$($E/K$ is an elliptic curve over number field $K$.), I cannot understand what are subgroups of finite index, thus I cannot grasp its completion.

Comment: The inverse system is just $M/U$, where $U$ runs over all finite index subgroups. Note that the set of finite index subgroups is partially ordered by inclusion and this post is a directed set.

Comment: I meant poset, not post. You also need to note that for $U \subset V$ we have a morphism $G/U \to G/V$ and these morphisms form s compatible system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two completions. What you're talking about is called the [profinite completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Profinite_completion), and it is defined for an arbitrary group $G$, not necessarily abelian, as the cofiltered limit of all finite quotients $G/N$. The inverse system has a unique homomorphism $G/N \to G/M$ whenever $N \subseteq M$ where $N, M$ are two finite index normal subgroups. This construction does not make any reference to a topology on $G$, and in fact induces a topology on $G$, namely the profinite topology.

It sounds to me like you're confusing it with the Cauchy completion of a topological abelian group which is something else (and uses a given topology). For example the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ but its Cauchy completion is just $\mathbb{Z}$.

As for the case of elliptic curves, by the [Mordell-Weil theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell%E2%80%93Weil_theorem) $E(K)$ is finitely generated, so it has the form $T \times \mathbb{Z}^r$ where $T$ is a finite abelian group and $r$ is the rank. We have that

- the profinite completion of a finite group is itself (straightforward exercise in the definition),
- profinite completion commutes with finite products (discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463290/do-profinite-completions-commute-with-direct-products)), and
- the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ as previously discussed.

So altogether we get that $\widehat{E(K)} \cong T \times \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^r$.